# Change in pitch on a flute due to blowing at a different angle

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

Why is it that the location of where the air hits the inside of a tube, the pitch is affected? When playing the flute, directing the air downwards lowers the pitch. Another student suggested that this is caused by more air inside the instrument, however my physics teacher countered that more air will affect the amplitude of the wave (volume), which I can comfrim as a flute player.  So why is it the frequency is affected, especially when calculating frequencies, this isn't a considered factor?

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! Your original title was "Pitch in a tube closed at one end," but actually a flute doesn't act physically like an asymmetric air column, it acts like a symmetric one. With all the tone holes closed, it plays 262 Hz, which has a wavelength equal to twice the length of the tube, not four times the length. In general you can't guess whether a wind instrument will act like a symmetric or asymmetric air column just by looking at the ends. I believe it depends on the mouthpiece/reed (in a flute, the "air reed") and the conical or cylindrical shape of bore.

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain whether the change in pitch you're describing is an octave leap, or a smaller change in intonation, or possibly either one depending on how you do it?

Comment: Intriguing question! After a little searching, I found this partial explanation by an acoustician who studies such effects for a living: https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/fluteacoustics.html#lipping. Essentially, it seems that by partially covering the embouchure hole with her lip, the flutist increases the acoustic impedance to the ambient atmosphere (i.e. makes it harder for the pressure wave to travel out of the hole), thereby increasing the effective length of the instrument. Since the pitch is inversely proportional to the length, "lipping down" lowers the pitch.